# How to change accept attribute of input type file based on select file type using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select list like this

```
<select asp-for="FileTypeIndex" class="form-control" id="FileTypeIndex" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<FileTypeIndex>()"></select>

<input type="file" class="form-control " accept="*.*" id="productfile" name="productfile">
```

I want to change the accept attribute of file input according to the selected FileTypeIndex by JQuery

```
  $('#FileTypeIndex').on('change',function() {
         var filytypeIndex=$('#FileTypeIndex').val();
        
         switch(filytypeIndex) {              
          case 1:
            $('#productfile').attr("accept", ".pdf");
            break;
          case 2:
          case 5:
            $('#productfile').attr("accept", ".mp4,.avi");
            break;
          case 3:
            $('#productfile').attr("accept", ".mp3");
            break;
            case 4:
            $('#productfile').attr("accept", ".jpg");
            break;
          default:
        }
  });
```

But it is always "*.*", and it won't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the datatype of `filytypeIndex` variable to number using `Number()` function of javascript.

Because in switch case gives 1,2,3 ... it is numbers

Your final code like below

```js
$('#FileTypeIndex').on('change', function () {
    var filytypeIndex = Number($('#FileTypeIndex').val());
    switch (filytypeIndex) {
        case 1:
            $('#productfile').attr("accept", ".pdf");
            break;
        case 2:
        case 5:
            $('#productfile').attr("accept", ".mp4,.avi");
            break;
        case 3:
            $('#productfile').attr("accept", ".mp3");
            break;
        case 4:
            $('#productfile').attr("accept", ".jpg");
            break;
        default:
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select asp-for="FileTypeIndex" class="form-control" id="FileTypeIndex" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<FileTypeIndex>()">
      <option value="1">1</option>  
      <option value="2">2</option>  
      <option value="3">3</option>  
      <option value="4">4</option>  
      <option value="5">5</option>  
</select>

<input type="file" class="form-control " accept="*.*" id="productfile" name="productfile">
```